# Chamar form após tela de loading

Tags: c#

Já verifiquei algumas respostas que foram feitas a respeito sobre fechar um form após fazer login e etc. Testei os demasiados métodos em minha função, mas não obtive sucesso.

**Logo o meu problema não se consiste a um login e sim a uma tela com um progressBar.**

Estou a fazer o seguinte: Tenho um form que apresenta uma tela de "loading" (progressBar) que após ter carregado toda a barra, ele deveria fecha esse form e chamar a um segundo form contendo dados.

O problema consiste em que, eu não consigo fechar o **form de loading (ele é o form de inicialização do programa).** Se conhecerem algum método ...

```
//primeiro form
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
   {
      progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value +2;
   }
   else if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
   {
      timer1.Enabled = false;
      Form2 f2 = new Form2();
      f2.Show(); // aqui chamo o segundo form
      //this.Close() // tentei essa função para fechar o Form1, mas sem sucesso também
   }
}
```

Comment: Considere seu form principal o form que ficará aberto na aplicação, e não o form loading, antes de você abrir o form principal, você exibe e fecha o loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, só fazer isso:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
   {
      progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value +2;
   }
   else if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
   {
      timer1.Enabled = false;
      Hide();
      Form2 f2 = new Form2();
      f2.Show(); // aqui chamo o segundo form
   }
}
```

Comment: Realmente muito simples mesmo, agradeço a ajuda !!

Comment: O método do Hide() não fecha o formulário como @user56742 havia comentado na resposta, ele somente esconde o mesmo.

Comment: Sim, mas é como se tivesse fechado o mesmo, acredito que não tem problema utilizar o Hide nesse problema.

Comment: Sim, problema não tem, é que a questão não ficou clara ai deu a entender que você queria fechar e não esconder o form.

Answer (score 2):

No seu projeto principal, no caso o projeto que estiver definido para inicializar sua aplicação, na classe Program.cs escreva o código da seguinte forma que vai funcionar.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        FrmLogin frmLogin = new FrmLogin();

        if (frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            Application.Run(new FrmPrincipal());
    }
}
```

Nesse caso eu trato a tela como uma caixa de diálogo e de acordo com o retorno do botão da tela de login eu abro ou não a tela principal.

Criar esse outro método e chama ele dentro do construtor

```
    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        // Call this procedure when the application starts.
        // Set to 1 second.
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);

        // Enable timer.
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Ficando das seguinte forma:

```
     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();

         InitializeTimer();
     }
```

E esse método que você havia criado deixe desssa forma:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Value + 10;
        }
        else if (progressBar1.Value == 100 && timer1.Enabled)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }
```

Testei e deu certo.

Comment: Ok, eu tinha tentado esse método antes. O problema é que quero sair da tela de loading onde só tem um progressBar e esconde-la ou até fecha-la para somente mostrar a tela principal.

Comment: Fiz um novo ajuste para funcionar como você falou

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi muito bem sua dúvida. Mas você quer iniciar um outro form primeiro invés do login, que é o inicial do seu programa? Seee por acaso for essa a dúvida, é só mudar isso http://prntscr.com/f6dpkg